# Symfony 4 Incomplete CSS loading

Tags: css, .htaccess, symfony

I just deployed my site on a VPS server that works under Debian10

I added the .htaccess file, the routes are working fine.

But I have a problem.

And I wonder how it is done.

However in dev mode, everything works fine.

The problem comes from the .htaccess file because when I delete this file the css works fine but the routes don't.

Except that I do not master regular expressions very well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#teste
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: There is documentation about configuring your web server in the Symfony website that could help you https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#using-mod-php-php-cgi-with-apache-2-4

Comment: Please invest a bit of time to revise your question. Fix the rendering of the code block. And also the code itself: it looks as if a copy and paste issue happened...

Comment: Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is in the wrong place, but apart from that there's nothing wrong with your `.htaccess` file. The problem is likely that you are using relative URL-paths to your CSS files. See this question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: What is the difference with "dev" mode?

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How does this address the OPs problem? (It doesn't)